# How to run Multiple PageFactory pages ONE By ONE using TestNG.XML?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I am trying to make POM (PageFactory) based TestNG framework, But i am facing issue with passing WebDriver instance to 2nd TestCase file..

This is my Test Base(to Initialise Browser and log4j)

```
public class TestBase {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static FileInputStream fip;
    public static Properties prop;
    //public static Logger APP_LOGS=null;
    //public static SoftAssert st=null;
    public static boolean TestFail=false;
    public static int temp=0;
    public static final Logger APP_LOGS=Logger.getLogger(TestBase.class.getName());

    public static WebDriver initialization() throws Throwable{
        fip=new FileInputStream("./Files/or.properties");
        prop=new Properties();
        prop.load(fip);
        //APP_LOGS.debug("properties file is loaded");
        String browser=prop.getProperty("browsertype");
            //System.out.println("5");
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("mozilla")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver.exe");
            driver= new FirefoxDriver();
            //APP_LOGS.debug("Mozilla fire fox browser started");
        }
        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "./drivers/IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
            //APP_LOGS.debug("InternetExplorer browser started");
        } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            //APP_LOGS.debug("Chrome browser started");
        }
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String log4jConfPath = "log4j.properties";
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
        APP_LOGS.info("Opened "+prop.getProperty("browsertype")+" browser");            
        APP_LOGS.info("Navigated to Seleniumeasy.com/test");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;

    }
```

Above code i am extending in my Test PAGE..i.e InputFormSubmitPage (Below)

```
public class InputFormSubmitPage extends TestBase{

    WebDriver driver;

    public InputFormSubmitPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    //INPUTFORM SUBMIT -- Objects Locators

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='treemenu']/li/ul/li[1]/a") WebElement inputformlink;     
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH, using="//*[@id='treemenu']/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]/a") WebElement inputFormSubmit;  
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='first_name'][placeholder='First Name']") WebElement firstName;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='last_name'][placeholder='Last Name']") WebElement lastName;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='email'][placeholder='E-Mail Address']") WebElement eMail;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='phone'][data-bv-field='phone']") WebElement phoneNumber;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='address'][placeholder='Address']") WebElement address;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='city'][placeholder='city']") WebElement city;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using=".form-control.selectpicker") WebElement state;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='zip'].form-control") WebElement zipCode;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="[name='comment'][placeholder='Project Description']") WebElement projDescription;
    @FindBy(how=How.CSS, using=".btn.btn-default") WebElement sendButton;
    //@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="div[class$='has-error']>div>small[data-bv-result='INVALID']") WebElement allFieldsValidationErrorMessages_Invalid; 
    //@FindBy(how=How.CSS, using="div[class$='has-error']>div>small[data-bv-result='VALID']") WebElement allFieldsValidationErrorMessages_Valid;

    @FindBy(css="div[class$='has-error']>div>small[data-bv-result='INVALID']") public List<WebElement> allFieldsValidationErrorMessages_Invalid;

public void enterInputFormDetails()
{
    inputformlink.click();
    inputFormSubmit.click();
    firstName.sendKeys("FirstName");
    lastName.sendKeys("LastName");
    eMail.sendKeys("eMail@email.com");
    phoneNumber.sendKeys("9008001242");
    address.sendKeys("1234, 1st street");
    city.sendKeys("City");

    //State Selector
    Select oneState= new Select(state);
    oneState.selectByIndex(3);

    zipCode.sendKeys("12345");
    projDescription.sendKeys("This is Project Description");
    sendButton.click();

        APP_LOGS.info("*****************InputFormSubmit Button is clicked*****************");

    }
```

Now in my TestCase i.e. InputFormSubmitPageTest i am able to initialising WebDriver... But here is the problem.. in my next test case.. if i pass the same line i.e. WebDriver driver=TestBase.initialization();browser is getting initialising again .. i jus want to avoid that.. But not sure how to perform  i am using TestNG.xml to run the sequential execution

```
public class InputFormSubmitPageTest { //My First TestCase

    @Test
    public void validatingFieldsData() throws Throwable
    {
        WebDriver driver=TestBase.initialization(); // this is where i am starting browser

        InputFormSubmitPage formSubmit=PageFactory.initElements(driver, InputFormSubmitPage.class);     
        formSubmit.inputFormLaunch();
        formSubmit.inputFormSubmitInValidValidations();
        formSubmit.enterInputFormDetails();
    }

}
```

My 2nd Testcase i.e. AjaxFormSubmitPageTest

```
public class AjaxFormSubmitPageTest { //My Send TestCase

    @Test
    public static void validatingFieldsData() throws Throwable
    {
        WebDriver driver=TestBase.initialization(); // this is where i am starting browser

        AjaxFormSubmitPage formSubmit=PageFactory.initElements(driver, AjaxFormSubmitPage.class);       
        formSubmit.inputFormLaunch();
        formSubmit.inputFormSubmitInValidValidations();
        formSubmit.enterInputFormDetails();         
    }       
}
```

My TestNG.xml contains following entries...

```
class name="testcases.InputFormSubmitPageTest"
class name="testcase.AjaxFormSubmitPageTest"
```

Comment: Use singleton class - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm refer this page for more details

Comment: not sure how Singleton can help here.

Comment: Put getting webDriver object method as singleton.so when you say driver.get(url), it will just load the new url instead of launching new driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a @BeforeClass and do your driver initialization there. 
Something like:

```
@BeforeClass
        public static void before() {
    WebDriver driver=TestBase.initialization();
    }
```

This will be executed only once and will do initialization.

In case you are only worried about the execution order, you will have to make 2 changes : 1. In your testng.xml file, you will have to add :

test name="Test" **preserve-order="true"**
This will ensure the execution order of the test class mentioned in the testng.xml file. Follow this link for more details http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/preserve-order-in-testng

In case you want to ensure the priority order within a class, you will have to do something like :

```
@Test(priority=1) public void Test1() {}

@Test(priority=2) public void Test2() {}

@Test(priority=3) public void Test3() {}
```

priority encourages execution order but does not guarantee the previous priority level has completed. test3 could start before test2 completes. If a guarantee is needed, then declare a dependency.

Unlike the solutions which declare dependencies, tests which use priority will execute even if one test fails. This problem with dependencies can be worked around with @Test(...alwaysRun = true...) according to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

Comment: thanks alot @anshulGupta for your time and solution it works